# Mvc Razor RadioButtonFor is checked by default if the value is set to 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Has anyone experienced this before and is there a reason behind it?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedWishlistId, 0, new { id = "newWishlist" })
```

The above line takes precedence over the

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedWishlistId, wishlist.Id, new { @checked = "checked"})
```

even though the `checked` attribute is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Id, value)
```

If `x.Id` equals `value`, the `checked` attribute will be set even if this attribute was not specified. It happens because `RadioButtonHelper` has its own custom check:

```
isChecked = model != null &&
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) &&
    String.Equals(model.ToString(), valueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

and then:

```
if (isChecked)
{
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
}
```

[InputExtensions.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the reference and explanation. Personally I think if I explicitly want to set `checked` attribute it should take priority over everything.